# Angular: Get reference of one directive instance on host from another directive

Tags: angular, directive

My template:

```
<div myDirective myOtherDirective>Hello World</div>
```

myDirective:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {
  private readonly otherDirective: MyOtherDirective; // How to instantiate this?
}
```

How can I get a reference to `myOtherDirective` from inside `MyDirective`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be available throught DI

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private otherDirective: MyOtherDirective) {}
}
```

It there's no such directive on the same element then make sure you use `@Optional` decorator.

Alternatively, you can pass it as an `@Input`

**my-other.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myOtherDirective]',
    exportAs: 'myOtherDirective'
})
export class MyOtherDirective {}
```

**template.html**

```
<div myDirective [otherDirective]="other" #other="myOtherDirective" 
      myOtherDirective>Hello World</div>
```

**my.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {
   @Input() otherDirective: MyOtherDirective;
}
```

Comment: I was kind of sceptical about constructor injection, since it might mess with the order of instantiation of the directives, or, a circular dependency if both the directives need to refer each other?

Comment: It's common pattern that Angular uses itself internally

Comment: Just a critique on the wording of this question - Does this work? "It should" isn't very confidence building.

I'll try this - but It would be nice to know for sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! However, could you please point me out any documentation related to this behaviour?