# Select FormGroup with Angular Directive

Tags: angular

I know that it's possible to select Angular reactive form controls for a custom directive like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[formControl], [formControlName]',
})
export class MyDirective {
    constructor(
        private controlDir: NgControl,
        private el: ElementRef
    ) {
        const control = controlDir.control;
    }
}
```

However, this approach does not work when selecting [formGroup] although it derives from AbstractControl as well (NullInjectorError is thrown). I also tried injecting `NgForm` instead of `NgControl` but without success.

Is there a way to access a FormGroup via Angular Directive?

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8cnyqd?embed=1&file=src/app/my-form-group.directive.ts)

Comment: Looking at the source code of the formControl directive https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a8134dcfd4be1cc4f04163029e495aefe215d024/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts#L53

I see they use the providers element to inject the ngControl
also if what you're looking to achieve is to extend the default formControl directive
you might need to name it diffrently and extend the native one

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to select an existing FormGroup to get access to its controls

Comment: In most cases in the angular component where you initialized the formGroup, 
with new Formgroup(...)
you can use the formGroup.controls reference to access it's controls
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

Comment: I know this, but I want to find the formGroups dynamically with an angular directive

Comment: Its Difficult to understand with this few information what dynamically implies in this context,
Another way to find all formGroup directives would be using 
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren
as follows 
@ViewChildren(FormGroup) viewChildren: QueryList<FormGroup>;

Comment: I want to create a custom angular directive. This directive shall use [formGroup] as selector (according to the example with the form controls, see above. But I don't need the ElementRef, I need the formGroup as FormGroup object (according to controlDir.control for form controls which returns the AbstractControl object of the selected control).

Comment: Could you provide a minimal stackblitz reproducing the issue ?
In my opinion you are missing the provider in the "custom" formGroup directive and that is why you get the NullInjectorError. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts
 looking at formDirectiveProvider

Comment: I added a stackblitz link

Comment: Why the -2 Voting? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247686/angular-get-reference-of-one-directive-instance-on-host-from-another-directive)

Was able to get the reference to the formGroup's controls as follows

```
   export class MyFormGroupDirective implements OnInit {
       constructor(...,private formGroup: FormGroupDirective) { 
           console.log(Object.keys(this.formGroup.form.controls))
       }
   ...}
```

Injecting the formGroupDirective inside the custom MyFormGroupDirective

[Here's the stackblitz fork with the above solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customformgroupdirectiveref?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-form-group.directive.ts)